# How to add the same field to all tables in CASE dataset with magik?

Tags: smallworld-gis, magik

I need to loop through all tables of my smallworld repository and  add UpdateUser field to all of them. The looping is easy but how can get a handle to case_objects collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make sure the CASE dataset is opened. The easiest way is to open the CASE application, that will open the CASE dataset too.

Next you can get a handle thru:
**gis_program_manager.databases[:case].collections[:sw_gis!case_object]**

You should use the method
**case_object.insert_field( name, e_name, type, key?, text?, text_name )**
to add fields.

Comment: Thanks. How is case_object.add_field is different from insert_field?